# How to convert slider value to integer in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, type-conversion, uislider

How to convert float from 0..1 to integer 0 to 255 in xcode for ios? thanx!

Comment: Why don't you set the max value of the slider to 255 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
float number = [slider value];
int value = (int)(number * 255)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `value` property of a `UISlider` is always a `float`. In addition to Nico's answer, you could also set the bounds on the slider to what you want by

```
[slider setMinimumValue:0.0];
[slider setMaximumValue:255.0];
```

Then, whenever you call `slider.value`, cast to an `int` by

```
(int)slider.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = (int)([slider value] * 255)
```

Comment: This is identical to @Nico's answer posted 20 minutes prior.